# How do I display output from two functions in two IDs at the same time in the same paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

So basically I want when I click a button for it to randomly generate an app idea using words from two arrays. I've been stuck for days now and I'm just not sure where the error is. When I try running just the second function and id it doesnt do anything so im thinking the problem lies within the function or the array. Did i name everything correctly? Please forgive me if i used any vocabulary wrong im very new

```
<html>
  <button onclick="randomizefunction(); randomizefunction2()">Give me an 
   app idea!</button>

  <p id="randomWord"; "randomWord2"></p>
  </html>

<script>
const myList = ["Calculator", "MOBA", "Fitness App", "Dating App"];
randomizeFunction()

function randomizeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("randomWord").innerHTML = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
myList.length)]
}
const myList2 = ["with lootboxes", "with video ads every 15 seconds", "with pay to win 
microstransactions"];
randomizeFunction2()

function randomizeFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("randomWord2").innerHTML = myList2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
myList2.length)]
}
</script>
```

Comment: A html element can not have multiple IDs

Comment: ahhh ok then. that still doesnt explain why the second function and id dont work when i only use them though

Comment: because it can't find an element with the Id "randomWord2"

Comment: do you think you could elaborate? even when i run it with just randomizeFunction2 and randomWord2 its not working. do I have an issue in the function?

Comment: please forgive me i am very new i started learning this week

Comment: I hope [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) article can help you understanding the id attribute.

Comment: On your button, the functions getting called in the `onclick` attribute are not spelled correctly. (upper and lower case)

Comment: @rndmlttrs Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional answers can be provided. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<span>` tags (each with its own ID) inside the `<p>` element to do what you want.

Note that only one element can use an ID name (i.e. ID names must be unique) ***and*** an element can only have one ID.

Classes are almost exactly like IDs, but: (a) multiple elements can have the same className, and (b) one element can have multiple classNames.

That is why many libraries (like Bootstrap) ***only*** use classes. *(The one place where IDs do something that classes cannot, is with [HTML Bookmarks](https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp#midcontentadcontainer))*. Apart from that, just use classes for everything.

Also, note that you have a typo in your button javascript: `randomizefunction` `!==` `randomizeFunction`.

Here's proof your code works:

```js
const myList = ["Calculator", "MOBA", "Fitness App", "Dating App"];
const myList2 = ["with lootboxes", "with video ads every 15 seconds", "with pay to win microstransactions"];

randomizeFunction();
randomizeFunction2();


function randomizeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("randomWord").innerHTML = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
myList.length)];
}
function randomizeFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("randomWord2").innerHTML = myList2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
myList2.length)];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="randomizeFunction(); randomizeFunction2()">Give me an 
 app idea!</button>

<p><span id="randomWord"></span> <span id="randomWord2"></span></p>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to select a correct answer when done (green checkmark), and upvote any answer(s) that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function doesn't run because you can't add more than one Id to an element.
If you remove your second Id, your html code looks like this:

```
<p id="randomWord"></p>
```

or you could use class names:

```
<p class="randomWord randomWord2"></p>
```

---

In case of using one Id your second function is not needed anymore.
If you want to use class names you need to change

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

to

```
document.querySelector(classname)
```

Comment: Not a problem. Dont forget to mark a helpful answer (green checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

Let's go this way, an HTML element can only have 1 `id` just as an employee can only have a single payment code in a company, and a single payment code can not be used to prepare a payment slip for 2 employees, once the first employee receives the payment, the code would be invalid, which means the next employee would go without pay :(

That's how it is with HTML, when an id is assigned to more than 1 element, the first element in the DOM tree would be the rightful owner.

Come to JavaScript, this language is CaseSensitive, functions, variables and so on must be treated in this manner.

```
<html>
    //<button onclick="randomizefunction(); randomizefunction2()">Give me an 
   app idea!</button>
    //check the function names for case-matching
    <button onclick="randomizeFunction(); randomizeFunction2()">Give me an 
   app idea!</button>

    //<p id="randomWord"; "randomWord2"></p>
    //two different elements for your purpose
    <p id="randomWord"></p>
    <p id="randomWord2"></p>
</html>

<script>
    const myList = ["Calculator", "MOBA", "Fitness App", "Dating App"];
    randomizeFunction()

    function randomizeFunction() {
        document.getElementById("randomWord").innerHTML = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() 
        * myList.length)]
    }
    const myList2 = ["with lootboxes", "with video ads every 15 seconds", "with pay to win 
                     microstransactions"];
    randomizeFunction2()

    function randomizeFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("randomWord2").innerHTML = myList2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
        myList2.length)]
    }
</script>
```

But in your own case, I guess what you want to achieve is to concatenate the result of the first function with that of the second function in the same `<p>` element, to achieve that, just use:

```
    function randomizeFunction2() {
        //note the use of the same `randomWord` (2)has been removed
        //also note the `+=` for concatenation
        document.getElementById("randomWord").innerHTML += myList2[Math.floor(Math.random() * myList2.length)]
    }
```